# Django: Cutting down on the number of apps (foreign key to local class or module class instead of app)

Tags: python, django, database, optimization, foreign-keys

When I was first learning, I'd just create an app for everything that gets represented in the database. It gets to be a really bloated though.

Take for example: app Car with the need for many Passengers.

In the past I'd just create two apps, car and passenger, add them to installed apps, and never touch passengers again. Well, if car has a lot of fields to keep track of, this adds up pretty quickly.

I hear it's good practice to use modules instead. So in the car app folder I create modules.py, and in it add class passenger:

```
class Passenger(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=32,
        null=False,
        blank=True
    )

    # relationships
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, null=False, blank=False)
```

After a syncdb, makemigrations, and migrate (with the feedback "no migrations to apply")

```
Car.objects.all()[0].passenger_set.all()
```

OperationalError: no such table: car_passenger

What do I have to do to get this table created? Is this good practice for reducing bloat with simple one to many fields? Does this need to be defined in the Car model instead? Do I need to add car.modules to installed apps?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of creating two separate apps for car and passenger just create one single app and in models create two classes one is car and another is passengers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating two separate apps for car and passenger just create one single app and in models create two classes one is car and another is passengers.

and then apply the query

```
car = Car.objects.all()[0]
pass = Passanger.objects.filter(car=car)
```

Try this way.